# Does this sentence mean "much like" or " don't much like"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

*Firstly sorry for my bad English.*

I'm translating an article about [wearable Smart Watches](http://www.phonearena.com/news/To-wearable-or-not-to-wearable_id64018), but there is something I'm curious about. Does the bold part of the following context mean that the author likes to know what all these new products do, or the author doesn't like to know?

> If 2014 was the dawn of wearables in the sense that it represents the
>   largest inroads made for a new product category, then I hope 2015 will
>   be the year that really prompts me to really go all-in with the
>   technology. **As much I like what it all does so far, I have not kept
>   any of the new “smart” wearables on my wrist for longer than a couple
>   weeks.**

Comment: I would suggest that it's a typo - it should probably be *"Much as I like what it all does so far,..."*

Comment: Or "**As much as** I like what it all does so far, ..."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's expressing the author's ambiguous feelings about the watches - effectively both of your possible meanings at the same time.

> "As much (as) I like what it all does so far..."

The author likes the features that a smart watch provides, **however**...

> "I have not kept any of the new "smart" wearables on my wrist for longer than a couple weeks."

The author has not continued to use the watches.

Though he or she appreciates the benefits of a smart watch, the author does not find those benefits sufficiently valuable to bother wearing one (for reasons unspecified in this excerpt.)

Note: The first "As" in the sentence is usually included but optional.  The second "(as)" is necessary.  I put it in parentheses above to make it clear that I added it to make the questioner's sentence grammatically correct.

Comment: I though this meaning is possible if it is **Much as I like what it all does so far, I haven't....** or **However much I like what it all does so far, I haven't....**. So is it also possible to mean the same thing with **as much....**?

Comment: @Man_From_India Yes, "As much as I like XXXXXX" is stating that you greatly enjoy XXXXXX, but is always followed by a negative statement.  "As much as I enjoy your company, I cannot date you."  There are any number of modified versions of this with a similar sentiment.  "As fast as my sports car can go, it's no match for a professional racer."  "As delicious as your mother's cake is, nothing can beat my grandma's."

Comment: I see what you're asking, I typoed in my answer.  It should read, "As much as", not simply, "As much."  My apologies.  I had put the omitted word "as" in the wrong sort of parentheses and the site hid it from view.

Comment: But Jason, the OP's quoted sentence is **As much ...** :O

Comment: Jason, I see you have put a first bracket around **as**, do you mean there that **as** is optional? I am asking because in google search it seems the first **as** is optional in **as much as**.

Comment: @Man_From_India I assumed that in the OP's sentence the author had made a mistake.  My parenthetical "as" was intended to point that out.  With only "As much I like" at the beginning, it is not grammatical.  As you note, the first *as* is optional, but not the second.